# How to run commands you can run on terminal in Java

Tags: java, cmd, exec, ag

So guys I want to execute a command that you can execute on the cmd in my Java program. After doing some study, I thought i found a way to do this. However, my code doesn't work.

My code is

```
import java.io.*;

public class CmdTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] command = {"ag","startTimes conf.js >> pro.txt"};
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.directory(new File("./test-java/"));
        Process p = builder.start();
    }
}
```

The program executes but produces no output. I tried using other commands like "ls -a", but still no output.

Can someone please help me debug this or suggest a better way of doing this? Thank you

Edit 1: I am executing this on a Mac. If that is necessary for debugging

Edit 2: The usual ls and other commands are working with the solutions that you guys have provided. I however want to use the ag (the_silver_searcher) command in the Java program. When i try that, i get the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ag startTimes conf.js >> pro.txt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you running this on a Windows or a Linux environment?

Comment: @AustinA, I am running this on a Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answers give you the information on how to solve your problem in code, but they don't give a reason why your code is not working.

When you execute a program on a shell, there's significant processing done by the shell, before the program is ever executed. Your command line

```
    String[] command = {"ag","startTimes conf.js >> pro.txt"};
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

assumes that the command `ag` is run with the *single* argument `startTimes conf.js >> pro.txt` - most likely not what you want to do. Let's go one step further: What if you wrote

```
    String[] command = {"ag","startTimes", "conf.js", ">>", "pro.txt"};
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

?

This would assume that the `ag` command knows about the `>>` parameter to redirect its output - and here is where the shell comes into play: The `>>` operator is an instruction *to the shell*, telling *it* what to do with the output from stdout of the process. The process `ag`, when started by the shell, never has an idea of this redirection and has no clue about `>>` and the target file name at all.

With this information, just use the code samples from any of the other answers. I won't copy them into mine for proper attribution.

Comment: thank you so much Olaf, your inputs really helped. i was finally able to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

While there is `ProcessBuilder`, I've always used `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");`

[Process Runtime.exec(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-)

It returns a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) which you can get the input and output streams of

Even if you stay with the `ProcessBuilder`, you should still have access to the `Process.get<Input/Output/Error>Stream()`

Comment: I get error - "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ag startTimes conf.js >> pro.txt": error=2, No such file or directory". What do you suggest i do?

Comment: @Sid try putting in the full filepath, it's probably running the command from the local directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the output of the process by opening an input stream from the process:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())) {
    System.out.println(reader.readLine()); // process the output stream somehow
}
```

Additionally you might the read the error stream ( `p.getErrorStream()`), which I often have done in a separate stream, in Java 8 you can use `redirectErrorStream(true)` on the `ProcessBuilder` to automatically add the error stream to the input stream. Of course you can't distinquish anymore from which stream the input comes, but it makes reading easier. If you don't read the input or error stream and the process's buffer becomes full the processes tend to pause until there is enough room in the buffer again.

Comment: I get error - "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ag startTimes conf.js >> pro.txt": error=2, No such file or directory". What do you suggest i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add

```
builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

before the start method which redirects the output to the console.

Comment: Hey ben, your solution works when i use commands like ls. But when i use the ag command, i get the error -

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ag startTimes conf.js >> pro.txt": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: What can i do now?

Comment: You are asking a new question. It would be fair to accept one of the two solutions provided to you and maybe post a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//"ls" command runs under the "sh" on linux(cmd.exe on windows), so first arg is "sh"    
//second arg "-c" tells "sh" which exact command should be executed
//"ls" is actual command
//"startTimes" as I understand is a file or directory, it is arg for "ls" command
//"conf.js" is second arg for "ls" command
new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "ls", "startTimes", "conf.js")
//set working dir for "sh" process"
            .directory(new File("./test-java/"))
//output will be written to "pro.txt" in working dir of "sh" process
            .redirectOutput(new File("./test-java/pro.txt"))
            .start();
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.